# Watir wait for more posts load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

The site which I want to scrape is having lazy loading with a scroll event. (infinite scroll)
I want to wait for more posts to load, but all posts have the same class name. So, I can't wait for an element with a specific class name to load. I don't want to use `sleep()` method.

Example Code:

```
<div class='posts'>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 // The following posts appear after scrolling. I want to fetch these posts
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
 <div class='single-post'></div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this issue? Is it possible to check if this div has more than 10 posts?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of the single-post divs to see if more have loaded. Depending on the markup of the page, you can do:

```
browser.divs(class: 'single-post').count
```

or, if the parent matters:

```
browser.div(class: 'posts').divs(class: 'single-post').count
```

This can be used to wait for the number of posts to increase:

```
# Find the original count
original_count = browser.divs(class: 'single-post').count

# Take an whatever action to trigger the loading of more posts
browser.scroll.to :bottom

# Wait for the count to increase
browser.wait_until do
  new_count = browser.divs(class: 'single-post').count
  new_count > original_count
end
```

Comment: Thank you, good job.. i also solved it like : `Watir::Wait.until { browser.div(class: 'posts').div(index: 25).exist? }` index number is up to you

Comment: @OğuzÇiçek I like your approach, and if you are going this route, you can just as easily do this with less code by: `browser.div(class: 'posts').div(index: 25).wait_until(&:exist?)`

Comment: You could probably shorten to even `browser.div(class: 'single-post', index: 25).wait_until(&:exists?)`